# Index of an array item in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table with an array column like:

```
+-Name-+
 array
  0: {"given_name":"B. A.", "surname":"Name1"}
  1: {"given_name":"A.", "surname":"Name2"}
  2: {"given_name":"C." "surname":"Name3"}
```

I would like to add one more element item "index" starting with 1 into an array to find the sequence of the author, like

```
+-Name-+
array
  0: {"given_name":"B. A.", "surname":"Name1", "index":"1"}
  1: {"given_name":"A.", "surname":"Name2", "index":"2"}
  2: {"given_name":"C." "surname":"Name3", "index":"3"}
```

How to do this in Scala, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using a UDF that maps each element of the array-typed column to include also the element index:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

case class Name(given_name: String, surname: String)
case class NameIdx(given_name: String, surname: String, index: Int)

val df = Seq(
  Seq(Name("John", "Doe"), Name("Jane", "Smith"), Name("Mike", "Davis")),
  Seq(Name("Rachel", "Smith"), Name("Steve", "Thompson"))
).toDF("name")

val addIndex = udf((names: Seq[Row]) => names.map{
  case name @ Row(gn: String, sn: String) => NameIdx(gn, sn, names.indexOf(name) + 1)
})

df.select(addIndex($"name").as("name")).show(false)
// +----------------------------------------------+
// |name                                          |
// +----------------------------------------------+
// |[[John,Doe,1], [Jane,Smith,2], [Mike,Davis,3]]|
// |[[Rachel,Smith,1], [Steve,Thompson,2]]        |
// +----------------------------------------------+
```

To produce JSON values, apply `to_json` as follows:

```
df.select(to_json(addIndex($"name")).as("name")).show(false)
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |name                                                                                                                                                 |
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |[{"given_name":"John","surname":"Doe","index":1},{"given_name":"Jane","surname":"Smith","index":2},{"given_name":"Mike","surname":"Davis","index":3}]|
// |[{"given_name":"Rachel","surname":"Smith","index":1},{"given_name":"Steve","surname":"Thompson","index":2}]                                          |
// +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Leo, It's adding the index value in the array, but the array item should have a label like // +----------------------------------------------+ // |name | // +----------------------------------------------+ // |[[given_name:John,surname:Doe,index:1], [given_name:Jane,surname:Smith, index:2], [given_name:Mike,surname:Davis,index:3]]| // +----------------------------------------------+

Comment: @VSr, if you want JSON values rather than arrays of `struct`s, just apply `to_json` as shown in the expanded answer.

Comment: Hi @Leo, I am getting Caused by: scala.MatchError: [Jane,null] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema) error when I have null value in the input. and also getting error: ':' expected but identifier found. when I have '-' in the item label, eg: "given-name" How this can be handled?